# Python Profanity Checker Error

Tags: python

The profanity checker seems to be working but does not return either (response: false) or response: true)

Here is a look at the code:

```
import urllib.request

    def read_text():
        quotes = open("/Users/sellis/Desktop/movie_quotes.rtf")
        contents_of_file = quotes.read()
        print(contents_of_file)
        quotes.close()
        check_profanity(contents_of_file)

    def check_profanity(text_to_check):
        connection = urllib.request.urlopen(" http://www.wdylike.com/profanity?q"+text_to_check)
        output = connection.read()
        print(output)
        connection.close()

    read_text()
```

When it is run  it comes up as:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf470
{\fonttbl\f0\fmodern\fcharset0 Courier;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red0\green0\blue0;}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\deftab720
\pard\pardeftab720\sl280\partightenfactor0

\f0\fs24 \cf2 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
\outl0\strokewidth0 \strokec2 -- Houston, we have a problem. (Apollo 13)\
\
-- Mama always said, life is like a box of chocolates. You never know what you are going to get. (Forrest Gump)\
\
-- You cant handle the truth. (A Few Good Men)\
\
-- I believe everything and I believe nothing. (A Shot in the Dark)\
}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sellis/Desktop/check_profanity.py", line 16, in <module>
    read_text()
  File "/Users/sellis/Desktop/check_profanity.py", line 8, in read_text
    check_profanity(contents_of_file)
  File "/Users/sellis/Desktop/check_profanity.py", line 11, in check_profanity
    connection = urllib.request.urlopen(" http://www.wdylike.com/profanity?q"+text_to_check)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 505: HTTP Version Not Supported
```

After the code runs it is supposed to show a response: false or a response: true depending on if after reading the code the function discovers that there is a cuss word

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python HTTP Error 505: HTTP Version Not Supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23715943/python-http-error-505-http-version-not-supported)

Comment: What should I do? Do I get rid of the duplicate? If so, how do you do that?

Comment: No, you don't have to get rid of your question. If it gets marked as duplicate, it may hang around as another way a user's search term might come across the answer. Though, you may want to change the title to something more specific to the error and not your specific task.

Comment: Yes, a function that doesn't contain a `return` statement will not return `True` or `False`.  So what's your question?

Comment: And you should tread lightly - it's much more difficult than it looks to make a profanity checker that avoids the [Scunthorpe problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).